# passwordless ssh for all machines on a network

Tags: linux, ssh, azure

I know the basic way to allow key based authentication between two servers is by using these three steps:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i remote_host
ssh remote_host
```

Using this approach I need to enter the password manually when I ssh into remote host, and then do the reverse to allow the ssh to go both ways.

The issue I am running into is I need 100 servers on the same network in Azure to be able to ssh into each other bi-directionally without passwords, and to be able to do this hopefully again.

Is there a way for me to do this for all machines on the same network easily, without having to set this up for each one?

Comment: Have you tried using a CM to do this for you?

Comment: No, can you please send me some information on what a cm is, I'm having trouble finding any information on the internet.

Comment: @GregL - what's a CM? - do we need to Google this too

Comment: CM = Configuration Manager. Puppet, Ansible, etc...

Comment: You could probably cobble something together in ansible.

Comment: There are certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to manage hundreds of servers you likely would be better off using some sort of configuration management tool such as puppet and chef, or ansible etc.

you still would have to set it up once but you can do much more than just ssh later so it would likely be worthwhile, for instance when you want to update the ssh key, a single change in the puppet master (or equivalent in other CMs) would suffice. for security it is recommended that you change your key once in a while.

Comment: that's using a canon to kill a fly - the question is how to copy ssh key to 100 hosts, you can do it with the 3 line script below or undertake a massive IT project.

Comment: so would I be able to use a CM to set up the ssh copy once between two machines, and I would be able to apply that to all 100?

Comment: you can go from bare metal to cloud bursting another 100 servers, it can handle copying files.

Comment: So I found that if I do this, I can give every server the same id_rsa and id_rsa.pub which simplifies this tremendously.

Comment: .....or run the script and copy the private key to all hosts. –

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in `cat /root/serverips.txt`; do
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $ip
done
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to enter the password for each machine in order for them to connect?

Comment: you have to do that anyway, you can't copy a file to a server without being authenticated

Comment: So that means I need to enter the password 100 times for each server thats 10000 times, is there really no other way?

Comment: yes, if you want it from every direction, otherwise pick a server and run the script.

Comment: each known_hosts file will need 100 entries, .....or run the script and copy the private key to all hosts.